# requirements.txt missing when installing Nashpy library

Tags: python, installation, pip, anaconda

I am new to python and am not able to install the library Nashpy. On https://nashpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/index.html#installing-nashpy the description of installing it is to simply type `pip install nashpy` into the Anaconda prompt if I understand correctly. However, when I do that, I receive the error below

> (base) C:\Users\Emanuel>pip install nashpy
> Collecting nashpy
> Using cached nashpy-0.0.22.tar.gz (11 kB)
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'C:\Users\Emanuel\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Emanuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dd2taahb\nashpy\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Emanuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dd2taahb\nashpy\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Emanuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dd2taahb\nashpy\pip-egg-info'
> cwd: C:\Users\Emanuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dd2taahb\nashpy
> Complete output (5 lines):
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "C:\Users\Emanuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dd2taahb\nashpy\setup.py", line 6, in 
> with open("requirements.txt") as f:
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
> ----------------------------------------
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

I've looked this issue up (especially how to create the needed requirements file) but none of the other threads solved my problem.

Thank you for your help!

P.S.: I have Python version 3.7.6, Anaconda version 4.8.3 (and installed through anaconda) Numpy version 1.18.1 and Scipy version 1.4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it, so I'll post the solution for future reference:

Download the file nashpy-0.0.23-py3-none-any.whl from https://pypi.org/project/nashpy/#files and execute

```
pip install nashpy-0.0.23-py3-none-any.whl
```

while making sure you have the required packages satisfying the version requirements and making sure that you are in the directory of the downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in `nashpy` version 0.0.22. Now there is a [release 0.0.23](https://pypi.org/project/nashpy/0.0.23/#files) so you can just install it with

```
pip --no-cache-dir install nashpy
```

PS. `--no-cache-dir` is to ignore your cached `nashpy-0.0.22.tar.gz`.